# Looking for «instance (Enum a, Bounded a) => IArray UArray a»

Tags: haskell, unboxing

I'm looking for a way to have `Enum a => UArray a` (which makes sense to me as we can trivially map enums to `Int` and back by `toEnum` and `fromEnum`)

So far I tried to steal code of `UArray Int` from [Data.Array.Base](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/array/0.3.0.1/doc/html/src/Data-Array-Base.html) and smuggle a few `toEnum`s and `fromEnum`s here and there:

```
{-# LANGUAGE MagicHash, UnboxedTuples #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}

module UArrays where

import           Data.Array.Base
import           Data.Array.ST
import           Data.Array.Unboxed

import           GHC.Base -- (Int(I#), Int#(..))
import           GHC.Prim -- (indexIntArray#, readIntArray#, writeIntArray#)
import           GHC.ST (ST(..), runST)

import           Unsafe.Coerce

instance (Enum a, Bounded a) => IArray UArray a where
    {-# INLINE bounds #-}
    bounds (UArray l u _ _) = (l, u)
    {-# INLINE numElements #-}
    numElements (UArray _ _ n _) = n
    {-# INLINE unsafeArray #-}
    unsafeArray lu ies = runST (unsafeArrayUArray lu ies minBound)
        {-# INLINE unsafeAt #-}
    unsafeAt (UArray _ _ _ arr#) (I# i#) =
        I# $ fromEnum (indexIntArray# arr# i#)
    {-# INLINE unsafeReplace #-}
    unsafeReplace arr ies = runST (unsafeReplaceUArray arr ies)
    {-# INLINE unsafeAccum #-}
    unsafeAccum f arr ies = runST (unsafeAccumUArray f arr ies)
    {-# INLINE unsafeAccumArray #-}
    unsafeAccumArray f initialValue lu ies =
      runST (unsafeAccumArrayUArray f initialValue lu ies)

-- data STUArray s i e = STUArray !i !i !Int (GHC.Prim.MutableByteArray# s)
instance (Enum a, Bounded a) => MArray (STUArray s) a (ST s) where
    {-# INLINE getBounds #-}
    getBounds (STUArray l u _ _) = return (l, u)
    {-# INLINE getNumElements #-}
    getNumElements (STUArray _ _ n _) = return n
    {-# INLINE unsafeNewArray_ #-}
    unsafeNewArray_ (l, u) = unsafeNewArraySTUArray_ (l, u) wORD_SCALE
    {-# INLINE newArray_ #-}
    newArray_ arrBounds = newArray arrBounds minBound
    {-# INLINE unsafeRead #-}
    -- unsafeRead :: GHC.Arr.Ix i => a i e -> Int -> m e
    unsafeRead (STUArray _ _ _ marr#) (I# i#) =
      ST $ \ s1# ->
      case readIntArray# marr# i# s1# of
        (# s2#, e# #) -> (# s2#, I# (toEnum e#) #)
    {-# INLINE unsafeWrite #-}
    -- unsafeWrite :: GHC.Arr.Ix i => a i e -> Int -> e -> m ()
    unsafeWrite (STUArray _ _ _ marr#) (I# i#) (I# e#) =
      ST $ \ s1# ->
      case writeIntArray# marr# (unsafeCoerce i#) (I# $ fromEnum e#) s1# of
        s2# -> (# s2#, () #)
```

But of course it doesn't compile:

```
[2 of 4] Compiling UArrays          ( UArrays.hs, interpreted )

UArrays.hs:27:14:
    Couldn't match expected type `Int#' with actual type `Int'
    In the return type of a call of `fromEnum'
    In the second argument of `($)', namely
      `fromEnum (indexIntArray# arr# i#)'
    In the expression: I# $ fromEnum (indexIntArray# arr# i#)

UArrays.hs:52:45:
    Couldn't match expected type `Int' with actual type `Int#'
    In the first argument of `toEnum', namely `e#'
    In the first argument of `I#', namely `(toEnum e#)'
    In the expression: I# (toEnum e#)

UArrays.hs:57:57:
    Couldn't match expected type `Int#' with actual type `Int'
    In the return type of a call of `fromEnum'
    In the second argument of `($)', namely `fromEnum e#'
    In the third argument of `writeIntArray#', namely
      `(I# $ fromEnum e#)'
Failed, modules loaded: Utils.
```

Also there is no magical `unboxInt :: Int -> Int#` in `GHC.*`, and pattern-matching on `I#` doesn't yield `Int` but an `Int#` instead, yet somehow `UArray Int` exists and works on `Int#`s.

I have also found a post about [making an UArray for newtypes](http://haskell.1045720.n5.nabble.com/UArray-for-newtypes-LogFloat-td3176830.html), but it doesn't seem to apply because it relies on `unsafeCoerce`.  I tried that but it made a funny `listArray (0, 54) $ cycle [Red, Yellow, Green]` in which all constructors were `Blue`.

Am I on the wrong track?

**Update:**

It works now, here is the source code:

- UArrays.hs: http://hpaste.org/56728
- BenchmarkUArray.hs: http://hpaste.org/56729
- Makefile: http://hpaste.org/56727

Comment: I don't think this is a very good idea. `fromEnum` and `toEnum` aren't _necessarily_ trivial for all instances, so this might end up being slower than a boxed array for some types.

Comment: @leftaroundabout in my (silly and artificial) case it resulted in cutting both time and space requirements by 70% for storing and handling an array of 100000 values of `data Color = Red | Yellow | Green | Blue`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to realize that `Int` is a boxed integer that is constructed from an unboxed integer `Int#` via the constructor `I#`. So:

```
-- These functions aren't practical; they just demonstrate the types.
unboxInt :: Int -> Int#
unboxInt (I# unboxed) = unboxed

boxInt :: Int# -> Int
boxInt = I#
```

Since `fromEnum` already returns a boxed integer, you don't have to re-box it by applying `I#` again, so in this code snippet, for instance:

```
{-I# $-} fromEnum (indexIntArray# arr# i#)
```

... you can simply leave out the `I#` constructor. Similarly, when using `toEnum`, you should apply the `I#` constructor to get a boxed integer out of an unboxed integer.

As @leftaroundabout mentioned, this boxing and unboxing in addition to the complexity that `fromEnum` and `toEnum` can have (Especially for tuples, etc) might lead to less performance compared to using simple boxed `Array`s.

Comment: Thanks!  Somehow I didn't understand how the unboxing was performed (by using `case` and matching against `I#`) but your answer has cleared things up.

Answer (score 2):

*Warning:* The function `fromEnum . toEnum` is not always a bijection, so this will not work for all enum types.  In particular, `Double` is an `Enum` instance, but `toEnum` just truncates `Double` values.

The reason for this is because `Enum` is the type class you must implement if you want to write expressions like `[0, 0.1 .. 1]`.  But generally speaking, what you're doing will just plain not work for some types.